# Hide one radio button from the group dynamically created from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I asked this question earlier but the post was not coherent or clear. So here we go again.

We dynamically generate a page using Javascript. This part of the code is used to create a set of radio buttons:

```
Dead, Trans, Hospital, Removed
```

Now I need to hide the radio button "Removed" when it's unchecked and only show the other 3. Javascript code:

```
//Create the main RadioDiv and append radio options
var radioQuestion = document.createElement("div");
radioQuestion.setAttribute("id", name + "RadioDiv");
fsRadio.appendChild(radioQuestion);
//For each radio button option do the following
for (var d = 0; d < optionList.length; d++) {
    var name = optionList[d].name;
    var value = optionList[d].value;
    //This creates the input field for each option
    var radioItem = document.createElement("input");
    radioItem.setAttribute('type', "radio");
    radioItem.setAttribute('name', flId);
    radioItem.setAttribute('id', flId + "_" + name);
    radioItem.setAttribute('value', value);

    if (flId != null && flId === 'reasonCode' 
        && name != null && name === 'Removed') {
         console.log("radio::"+flId + "_" + name);
         //Code to hide the button here?
    }

    if (status === null || status === "" ||
        status === false ||
        typeof status === 'undefined') {
        radioItem.setAttribute('class',
            "inactive-field");
        radioItem.setAttribute('disabled', "disabled");
    } else if (status === true) {
        radioItem
            .setAttribute('class', "active-field");
    }

    //This creates the label
    var radioLabel = document.createElement("label");
    radioLabel.setAttribute('for', flId + "_" + name);
    radioLabel.textContent = name;
    var objDiv = document.createElement("div");
    objDiv.setAttribute('class', "q-radio");
    objDiv.appendChild(radioItem);
    objDiv.appendChild(radioLabel);
    //Append all radio buttons to the main RadioDiv - radioQuestion
    radioQuestion.appendChild(objDiv);
    if (radioItem.value == flValue && flValue != null && flValue != undefined && flValue != "") {
        radioItem.setAttribute('checked', "checked");
    } //end of if statement

} //end of For loop
```

Hopefully this time the post is relevant. Thanks so much for your help. Also if any more details needed, please do let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Is removing `Removed` from `optionList ` an option? It won't need to be hidden if it's never created...

Comment: @jessh That's actually a great idea. Thanks much. Will look into it